# M2: Efficient way to sort by brand label and then by product category

Tags: magento2

Early days for me on M2, so struggling with relatively basic things like this - I am trying to figure out an efficient way to retrieve a product collection, then sort it by manufacturer/brand label (rather than the option ID) and then by each category within that brand.

So far, I have the following:

```
$collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
$collection->setVisibility($this->catalogProductVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());

$collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setPageSize($this->getPageSize())
        ->setCurPage($this->getRequest()->getParam($this->getData('page_var_name'), 1))
        ->setOrder(array('brand'), $this->getSortOrder());
```

Is there a way to modify the collection to order the product collection by the brand value rather than the option ID, which is currently what's happening?

Then the more complex part I think is how to order the products by category within each brand, without doing additional DB lookups. There's also the issue in that products can be assigned to multiple categories.

So far, I'm able to split out the products by brand on the frontend with a little bit of logic in the template, however I'm aware of starting to add additional logic which could be potentially be handled in how the collection is filtered.

Any pointers in the right direction greatly appreciated.